# Is there a way to filter all columns of a pandas dataframe against a list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a list of taxonomic classifications that are not uniform across their levels within the list and I want to filter all the columns of a data-frame against each item of the list to produce a singular sub-data-frame.

An example list would be

```
['Sk1','Sub1','Family 3','Clade C']
```

my actual list has 23 items.

An example data-frame that looks like this and my actual dataframe has 1100 rows:

| Species | Super kingdom | Subkingdom | Clade | Class | Family |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Species 1 | SK1 | Sub1 | Clade A | Class I | Family 1 |
| Species 2 | SK2 | Sub2 | Clade B | Class II | Family 2 |
| Species 3 | SK3 | Sub3 | Clade C | Class III | Family 3 |
| Species 4 | Sk4 | Sub4 | Clade D | Class IV | Family 4 |

So filtering the frame against the list against the list should give:

| Species | Super kingdom | Subkingdom | Clade | Class | Family |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Species 1 | SK1 | Sub1 | Clade A | Class I | Family 1 |
| Species 3 | SK3 | Sub3 | Clade C | Class III | Family 3 |

The closest I have come to some solutions is to use np and pandas as:

```
mask = np.column_stack([taxonframe[col].str.contains(Query, na=False) for col in taxonframe])
taxonframe.loc[mask.any(axis=1)]
```

But this one would need me to loop though the list of queries and make a dataframe for each item in the list and somehow merge 23 dataframes (This one I am trying to avoid).

OR

I could use `itertuples()` on each row and do a string search on each row as a list and then convert them back to a new dataframe-if there is nothing else I guess I can work with this. Is there an elegant  pandas method to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming other columns cannot contain the same strings from other columns (e.g. `Clade` column cannot contain `Family 3`, etc.), you can use `isin` + `any` to create a boolean mask to filter `df`:

```
out = df[df.isin(['Sk1','Sub1','Family 3','Clade C']).any(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
     Species Super kingdom Subkingdom    Clade      Class    Family
0  Species 1           SK1       Sub1  Clade A    Class I  Family 1
2  Species 3           SK3       Sub3  Clade C  Class III  Family 3
```

Comment: This is definitely a start. Unfortunately the bulk data is a bit too big and asymmetrical for me to comment on the assumption. How does that matter exactly? Is it not filtering for rows?

Comment: @TangentRunner It's checking if any element in `df` contain any element in the list. So it returns True if `Species` column contains `"Family 3"` for example. But that doesn't seem to be the case for your case, so you're safe.